# How to use loop in R to average only the negative number up until you see a number with absolute value>1 in a vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector A=c(0.866,-0.142,-0.680,1.600,-1.068)

How can I use loop to average only the negative numbers up until the first number with absolute value >1?

I'm thinking about nesting a while loop within a for loop, but I'm not sure whether it's a right track.

Thank you!

Comment: So what's the desired output in this case? mean of second and third numbers only?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one without loop?

```
A=c(0.866,-0.142,-0.680,1.600,-1.068)

mean(A[cumprod(abs(A) <= 1) & A<0])
[1] -0.411
```

`cumprod(abs(A) <= 1)` will return true till first value with absolute value greater than 1 occurs, combining it `A<0` will return only negative values.  You can take mean thereafter.